# What is the origin of prions?

Tags: evolution, prion

We know something about the origin of the first cell. But what do we know about prions? How did they originate?

Comment: Well, it's not like we know the origin of cells.

Comment: @Bird - I agree with Eli... what do you mean by "we know the origin of the first cell"?

Answer (score 6):

The computational study by [Ehsani et al., 2011,](http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0026800) argues that an ancestor metal-ion transporter gene ZIP served as the initial template for the prion founder gene, where the same author produced a [2012 paper](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3609057/) that said this was probably a product of a spliced LIV-1 ZIP transcript that became reverse transcribed and inserted into the host genome. Thus, evidence in part points to a *retrogene* origin for prions (mediated by a retrovirus, especially since the gene is integrated into the host w/ no introns). They go on to state that two genomic rearrangements spanning hundreds of millions of years serve as the basis for the prion founder gene: A cysteine flanked core element inserted into the ZIP ectodomain, and then the insertion of a spliced, C-truncated ZIP transcript.

I don't think the evolutionary origin of prions are very well understood, yet, but I will try to find more recent data on the subject.